# Is it possible for the bot to randomize 2 colors for a message?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, bots

I'm using the decimal color, 6275760 in my embed, but I wanted him to use 16777201 as well, and when he sent the embed he sent it with one of these two colors

```
if (!args.length)
  return message.channel.send({
    embed: {
      color: 6275760,
      description: `<:FubukiX:749212433951883264> | ${message.author}, You need to put a message.`,
      footer: {
        text: `   | Exemple: !say hello`,
      },
    },
  });
```

Comment: `color: Math.random() < 0.5 ? 6275760 : 16777201,`

Comment: Just a side note, I would *highly* recommend putting those numbers in hex. `color: 0x5fc2b0` is a lot easier to understand as an RGB value than the decimal equivalent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, and all you need to do is add this.

```js
// Array of all the colors you want to be randomized, add as much as you want.
const colorArray = [16777201, 6275760];
// Randomizing a number within the length of colorArray
const rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * colorArray.length);
// Defining the color by picking a random color from the colorArray
const color = colorArray[rand];
if (!args.length)
 return message.channel.send({
  embed: {
   color: color,
   description: `<:FubukiX:749212433951883264> | ${message.author}, You need to put a message.`,
   footer: {
    text: `   | Exemple: !say hello`,
   },
  },
 }); // Define color as `color` which is the randomized color we defined above
```